# Character encoding in javascript file and a simple php file

Tags: php, special-characters

I got problem with some special characters. I have defined the meta tag as

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

so far so good. But in one occassion I have a select tag with many options with many special characters. I got problem showing (å ä ö). They are defined in .js file and are appended to the document using DOM. Pls. are there any solution except using &... forgot the name for that type.

Second character problem I have is in php. I try to send an email with Amazon SES.

```
<?php

$message['Body.Html.Data'] = "Please Confirm that you are a Tönt by clicking on this link"." ....<a href='s'>Tönt</a>";
$message['Body.Html.Charset'] = 'utf-8';

?>
```

the ö is not showing properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

At the very top of your PHP file, no need to use http-equiv metas when you can send some real http headers ;-)

Also check if your files (both PHP and JS) are encoded in UTF8 in your editor.
Setting an UTF8 header on non UTF8 files will produce strange results for sure!

Comment: All my special characters problems are now resolved. It has always been my IDE's fault